# In Rsyslog, how do you replace regex matches with custom text?

Tags: logging, rsyslog

I'm trying to capture text via regular expression and replace the text with a custom string.

My current code successfully captures IP addresses, but I don't know how to replace the IP address with custom text along with the rest of the message:

```
$Template privateIP,"%TIMESTAMP% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag% %msg:R,ERE,0,DFLT:([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}--end%\n"
```

My first thought is to somehow move the regex out of the template (i.e. with some RainerScript) and create a new field/variable `modded_msg` that is set to a modified `msg` property. And then use `%modded_msg%` in the $Template.

I've tried multiple times (thanks, ChatGPT), but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example can check the msg property for an IP address and then replace all occurrences of it in the message by some string, depending on the address.

```
set $.myip = re_extract($msg, "(([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})", 0, 1, 0);
if ($.myip == 0) then  set $.mymsg = $msg;
else{
 if ($.myip=="192.1.2.3") then
  set $.mymsg = replace($msg, $.myip, "SPECIALIP");
 else
  set $.mymsg = replace($msg, $.myip, "boringip");
}
template(name="mytemplate" type="string" string="%TIMESTAMP% %$.mymsg%\n")
action(type="omfile" file="output" template="mytemplate")
```

`re_extract()` looks for the regexp in the property. Note the extra `()` so
we can extract capture group 1, the whole match. Also, the `\` is doubled. The last parameter is 0,
returned on failure. The returned string is saved in a local variable `$.myip`.

`replace()` replaces all occurrences of the string in the property, and
returns the result in another local variable. The templace uses this local
variable.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: For anyone coming later, it looks like I was originally forgetting to use semicolons on my RainerScript :facepalm: